# Automatic running of SQL script when a new database is created

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgagent

I need to run some SQL scripts (which are basically SELECT queries) every time some new data enters the database.

When I say enters the database, I do not mean INSERT/UPDATE queries executed on an existing database/table(s), but rather ***every time a new database is created***.

I am using PostgreSQL as my SQL DBMS.

I have tried many approaches but none of them suit my requirement -

1. [***pgAgent/pg_cron***](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgagent_jobs.html) - requires a time constraint to be specified. Can only be triggered periodically.
2. [***SQL TRIGGER***](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) - can be applied only on a database (**INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE** trigger to check if a query has been executed on a database, i.e., assuming the database already exists)

I am yet to try the usage of a Procedural Language (PL/PgSQL, PL/PERL), but it would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction before I proceed.

---

TL;DR:
I need to run a SQL script on a PostgreSQL installation every time a new database is created (on a given server).

Comment: what exactly does this SQL script do?

Comment: It's a simple SELECT query which runs on a specific table which will be present in the newly inserted database.

Comment: If you want to define default table **statically**, template database might be helpful. This can't run SQL script though. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/manage-ag-templatedbs.html

Comment: Usually, the one that creates the database is also responsible for initializing it, if necessary. Why is that not an option for you? And if it is just about some `SELECT` queries where should the output go or do you discard it? Do the `SELECT` statements _trigger_ something inside the new created + initialized database?